# Angular $http post working in application but REST Client not working for same data

Tags: json, laravel, postman, rest-client, angular-http

I am sending data through post function in angular and it works fine.

```
$scope.contact_details = [
    {"name":"Username",
     "email":"username@gmail.com",
     "mobile":"XXXXXXXXXX",
    }]

var data = {
        contact_details : $scope.contact_details
    };

var url = API_URL + "/addcontacts?token=" + token ;

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $.param(data),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    }).success(function(response) {

        console.log("MyContactDetails : ",response);

    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
```

When I use POSTMAN or RESTClient, I enter the url with token and select method POST. I paste the following in body

```
[{"name":"Username","email":"username@gmail.com","mobile":"XXXXXXXXXX",}]
```

This does not work and I get error in my Laravel function :-

```
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

My Laravel function in controller :-

```
public function addContact(Request $request){
    $contacts = $request->input('contact_details');
    $company_id = Auth::guard('api')->user()->company_id;

    foreach($contacts as $contact){
        $addContact = new ContactList();
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `[{"name":"Username","email":"username@gmail.com","mobile":"XXXXXXXXXX",}]` `contact_details` is empty.

Try:
`[{"contact_details":{"name":"Username","email":"username@gmail.com","mobile":"XXXXXXXXXX"}}]`

Comment: same error - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ```{"contact_details":{"name":"Username","email":"username@gmail.com","mobile":"XXXXXXXXXX"}}```

Comment: no did not work, I am doing something wrong...trying to figure out